# Unknown command: 'react-dom'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, react-router-dom

I'm creating a react project and I wrote this command in terminal :

```
npm -i -s react-dom react-router-dom node-sass
```

My version of react-dom in my package.json is 17.0.2

When I press enter I get this in return : `Unknown command: 'react-dom'`

I someone can help me I would be glad !

Thanks

Comment: What does `npm -i` mean? Maybe you want `npm i` / `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to install the command is `install` or just `i`.

```
npm install -s react-dom react-router-dom node-sass
npm i -s react-dom react-router-dom node-sass
```

Comment: Also, careful with `react-router-dom` as it just recently release a major version (v6) with many breaking changes, so if you are following along in tutorials that are using the previous version you may want to `npm i -s react-dom react-router-dom@5 node-sass`.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use create react app

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started